# fopen is not opening a file stream... how do I resolve this?

Tags: c, fopen

I am trying to write a file and append data to it.

Here is a snippet of my code.  thresh is an unsigned short.

```
    FILE *fp_th;
    fp_th = fopen("threshold.txt", "a");
    printf("opening file failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
fprintf(fp_th,"%d ", thresh);
    fclose(fp_th);
```

Before it has worked fine, but I've changed some of my code and all of a sudden it doesn't print out anymore.

I've confirmed that fopen isn't opening a file stream with

```
printf(" check fp_th = %p \n", fp_th);
```

It prints out `check fp_th = 00000000`.

EDIT: Added `printf("opening file failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));` after fopen.  Output says no error.  Does it lie?  Odd..

The odd thing is that I am writing and appending a similar file, and yet that file works fine.  How do you resolve a fopen that returns a NULL?  Why does it happen?  Thanks!

Comment: Stuff in my program that shouldn't matter, I would think.  You folks would just need to know what I am trying to write out which is my variable thresh, a unsigned short.  The fprintf is in a loop.  However, fopen is much before this loop.  My threshold.txt is never created.  Any ideas?

Comment: "Stuff in my program that shouldn't matter" Famous last words.

Comment: LOL ... I want to believe that is the case.  But time and time again, I know it backfires.  However, doing a fopen would be straight forward I would think (backfires again XP)

Comment: When fopen fails, it sets the `errno` variable.  Try adding the following line if it fails (check if fp_th is NULL):  

`perror("fopen failed");`

and don't forget to `#include <errno.h>`

Edit:  Look at Zulan's answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly

```
fprintf(fp_th,"%d ", thresh);
```

Will normally buffer output until you close the file, or the internal FILE* buffer is full.  You might not see any output in the file immediatly

You could fflush() the FILE* to have it written out to the file when you decide.

```
fprintf(fp_th,"%d ", thresh);
fflush(fp_th);
```

Secondly

```
printf(" check fp_th = %d \n", fp_th);
```

This does not check that `fp_th` is invalid. It just prints the pointer value of fp_th as a signed integer, and -7323824 might be as good as a value as any, this will be even less meaningful, and probably undefined if the size of your pointers are not the same as the size of an int.

To print a pointer you should use %p

```
printf(" check fp_th = %p \n", fp_th);
```

fopen returns NULL if it fails, you should check for that to learn if opening the file failed or not.

```
FILE *fp_th;
fp_th = fopen("threshold.txt", "a");
if(fp_th == NULL) {
   printf("opening file failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
   return;
}
```

Comment: Oh, hm I got the output messed up with the file that did open.  When doing printing to a %p, I get 00000000 which is indeed the NULL pointer.  Updating results and question.  How would you resolve a NULL return in a printf?

Comment: @O_O If you follow the above code, and do `printf("opening file failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));` when fopen returns NULL, you'll get a message telling you why it failed. (youi'll need to `#include <errno.h>`, and don't put any other calls inbetween fopen() and that printf

Comment: Interesting.. when I did `printf("opening file failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));`, it says no error.  Very odd..

Comment: @O_O That's because you either have an error in your code, or you didn't do what I said, and you placed some code inbetween fopen and the printf.

Answer (score 3):

First, always check the return value of `fopen` for NULL, which means failure.

To find out what went wrong during the file open, you can use `perror`.

```
  if (fp_th == NULL) {
    perror ("Error opening threshold file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

If you still cannot figure out while you get `permission denied` or `No such file or directory`, you can use `strace` (assuming Linux) and to look for the corresponding system call.

Answer (score 0):

> Before it has worked fine, but I've changed some of my code and all of a sudden it doesn't print out anymore.

If your code changed the current working directory, this can cause the file to not be found, as you're not providing a full path.  In this case, `fp_th` should be a null pointer, which is something for which you could check.  Your print suggests that it's not returning a null pointer, but rather did open the file.  For details, see [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/).

Comment: I mixed up my answers and indeed, it is returning a null pointer.  Any advice for resolving a NULL return in a fopen?  Thanks.

Comment: @O_O: As I said, this is probably due ot something changing the current directory.  Try using a full path to the file, and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. My code was openning N-1 files but mysteriously crashed in the Nth file, although that file definitely existed ...

perror revealed that I actually never closed all these files -to my embarassment, I had forgotten fclose(fd)...

I didn't use perror so far, but I now realize how valuable it is. :)